# How do I Make Google Apps Script serve XML to IE 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-apps-script, xmlhttprequest, google-apps

I have a google app script attached to a spreadsheet. It's deployed as a web app. When accessed, it returns XML.

```
function doGet()
{
  var xml = createXML_(getSheetData_())
  Logger.log("\n" + xml);
  xml = ContentService.createTextOutput(xml);
  xml.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);
  return xml;
}
```

I have javascript in a webpage that retrieves the XML from this, with a GET request, using XMLHttpRequest() like normal. It then traverses the XML and builds a table from the data.

In Chrome and Firefox, this all works perfectly. However, in IE11, it doesn't work.

Upon further examination (in IE's inspect thing), the XML being returned to IE is:

`<Permission Denied>`

and that's it.

How do I make my google app script return the XML when requested by Internet Explorer?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're trying to cater for IE?

Comment: It's for a client's website, so it should work with every major browser. It works in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that Google app script that is deployed as a web app on another domain and your web page is hosted on another domain from where you are trying to retrieve the XML using JS then it can be possible that IE is preventing you from accessing the resources across different domains.

I suggest you try to go to the `Internet options-> Security tab-> Select the desired zone-> Custom level` then **enabled** the **Access data sources across domains** option under the **Miscellaneous** category.

[image]

Restart the machine and again try to check for the issue.

If the issue still persists then I suggest you try to provide detailed steps with the sample code to reproduce the issue and also try to share the snapshot of the error may help to understand the issue in a better way.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is what's going on here. However, it's for a client's business, so I don't think I can just tell him to tell his customers to change their internet explorer settings.

I may have to just bite the bullet and add different methods of outputting the data to the google app script, such as directly outputting a table and seeing if I can put it in an iframe or something.

Comment: You can inform your client to test with this setting to confirm whether the issue caused by the cross-domain request. If the issue gets fixed with this setting then your client can configure this setting via group policy to apply it to the affected machines.